# Does line-height in css work in a single line of text?

Tags: class, css

This is my css styling of my header

> h2{
>   background: url(h2_trigger_a.gif) no-repeat;
>   height: 46px;
>   line-height: 46px;
>   }

Now, when i type some word in it, the word suppose to be out of the image because the line-height is same as the height of the text , but it is still inside it, why?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, yes, `line-height` works on a single line of text. Given a certain `line-height`, the browser will attempt to render the text in the middle of that line-height. So if the element has a `height` of `46px` and a `line-height` of `46px`, and assuming the `font-size` is `30px`, there will be `(46-30)/2 = 8px` open above and below the text.

So the `line-height` property, when used with only one line of text, can be used to keep text vertically centered by setting it to the same value as `height`.

Comment: how if i have multiple lines? The browser also use this calculation? or start from the second line the browser use the line-height that i given

Comment: @dramasea: Yes, on the second line, the browser will use the same calculation. You might have a misunderstanding of the `line-height` property; it only applies to the spacing used between text in an element. It results in lines of text appearing closer together or further apart.

Comment: Thanks, so if i want my space between the 2 line of text to 30px, and my text is 20px i need to use the calculation of (line-height - 20) = 30px ? It's really annoying if i want to count this everytime i want to use the line-height function

Comment: @HermanSchaaf: Without a coding example, it is tough to understand your answer. Please demonstrate on www.jsfiddle.net with simple tags like <p>.

Comment: @user514892 http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dim_line-height_pixel

Answer (score 1):

Just use: `padding-top: 46px` , please note line-height will NOT be added to the `height`
[read more](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/line-height).

**EDIT**: when I say it won't be added, I mean it can't be understood as:
`Final height = height + line-height`

Answer (score 0):

Try using margin-top: -46px;. That will work for sure.